# Resolving a promise in Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a service, lets call it `AccountService` which exposes a method called `getAccounts(customerId)` among others.

In its implementation all it does is to fire up a $http GET request and return a promise to the calling controller which will put the returned array of accounts in the controller scope once resolved.

On a simplified view all looks like below:

```
// The service
.factory('AccountService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _getAccounts = function(customerId) {
        var request = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'url': 'http://localhost:8081/accounts/' + customerId
        };
        return $(request);
    };

    return {
        getAccounts: _getAccounts
    };
}]);

// Inside the conntroller
AccountService.getAccounts($scope.customerId)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.accounts = response.data;
    });
```

So once the promise will resolve the controller scope will get populated with the list of accounts.

Note that I kept the above code as simple as I could to get you the idea of what my problem is but in reality it will be code to deal with exceptions, watcher to refresh, etc. Everything works fine.

My problem is that this AccountService is used from lots of controllers and putting the promise resolve in all of these looks to me not only repeating all this boiler plate resolver code but also complicating the unit testing as I am obliged to r/test both successful and exception scenarios in every single controller test.

So my question is:
Is there a nice way to resolve the promise in the service and return the response to the controller, not the promise?

Please note I am a very beginner with Angular and JS so please be gentle if my question looks naive. I have heaps of java experience and my mind seems to go java like everywhere which may not be the case.

Thank you in advance for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original question:

> Is there a nice way to resolve the promise in the service and return the response to the controller, not the promise?

In my opinion, no, there isn't. It boils down to the way asynchronous calls work - you either pass a callback (and the method returns nothing), or you don't pass a callback and the method returns an object which will be notified (a promise). There may be some workarounds, but I don't think it gets nicer than that.

One way to partially reduce the boilerplate is to use a `catch` in the service, and return the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Methods_2) returned by it instead.

Consider the following extremely simplified example:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('NetworkRequests', [
    function() {
      var _getData = function() {
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var a = true,
              data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

          if (a) {
            resolve(data);
          } else {
            reject('Rejection reason: ...');  
          }
        });

        return promise.catch((error) => {
          // Notify some error handling service etc.
          console.log(error);
          return [];
        });
      };

      return {
        getData: _getData
      };  
    }
  ]);
```

The promise variable would be the result from your http request. You should return some data in the catch function that makes sense in the controller context (e.g. empty array). Then you don't have to bother with error handling in the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('DataController', ['NetworkRequests',
    function(NetworkRequests) {
      NetworkRequests.getData().then((data) => {
        this.data = data;
      });
    }
  ]);
```

Again, this doesn't solve the complete issue, but at least the error handling part can be encapsulated in the service.

Comment: Yes you are right and I think trying to make an asynchronous thing synchronous is not a great idea. Again I was confused by my Java way of thinking where you can block a thread until a `java.util.concurrent.Future` is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can design in such a way that once your `$http` is done with fetching the data, store it your factory variable (somewhat a cache), and for subsequent factory calls, you check if the cache has such data. If yes, return the cache data, else call the `$http` calls.

Here is the code:

```
.factory('AccountService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  var cachedData = null;
  var defered = $q.defer(); //create our own defered object
  var _getAccounts = function(customerId) {
    if (cachedData !== null) {
      console.log('get from cachedData')
      defered.resolve(cachedData); // resolve it so that the data is passed outside
      return defered.promise; //return your own promise if cached data is found
    } else {
      var request = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': 'mockdata.json'
      };
      return $http(request).then((response) => { //return a normal $http promise if it is not.
        console.log('get from $http');
        cachedData = response.data;
        return cachedData;
      });
    }
  };

  return {
    getAccounts: _getAccounts
  };
}]);
```

Here is the [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qLkeaQ6U00FZAshj3XGA?p=preview). You can open up the console, and click the GetData button. You will see that first time it logs `get from $http`, where as subsequent calls it logs `get from cachedData`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what I asked for. You still resolve the promise in the controller which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. See your piece of code `AccountService.getAccounts().then(...)`

Comment: @Julian, you will have to use resolve the promise, else the return type of `getAccounts()` will be different. If your goal is to avoid using `.then`, then that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to reuse an object and fill it with data. It is used by ngResource.

It is something like

```
var data = [];

function getAccounts(customerId) {
    var promise = $http(...).then((response) => {
      Object.assign(promise.data, response.data)
    });

    promise.data = [];

    return promise;
};
```

Data is available for binding as `$scope.accounts = AccountService.getAccounts(...).data`. The obvious drawback is that there is a splash of unloaded content.

Another way is the one you've mentioned. It is being used most frequently. If there is a problem with WET code in controllers, it should be treated by eliminating WET code with class inheritance, not by changing the way it works.

Yet another way is the recommended one. Using a router and route/state resolvers eliminates the need for asynchronously loaded data. The data resolved in resolver is injected into route template as an array.